# Get file contents from text file in Firebase storage - Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

In my project I let people log their dive sessions and then upload them to firebase storage. When they have done that, other users or themselves can access them by an id. I store the logged dives as textdocuments on firebase. The problem is that I can't find a way to get the file contents.

This is all I got:

`val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("dives/" + "436 204")`

Note: This is just an example id

Comment: To get the `436 204` image, first you need to get it's downloar url. Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this.

Comment: I don't want to get the image. I want to get the text. 436 204 is a textdocument.

Comment: In the same you get the image, you can get any other file. The url of the file is needed.

Comment: How do I need it?

Comment: Why or how? You need it to get the content of your file.

Comment: Why do I need it